# fxml combobox, get the selected value into javafx

Tags: combobox, javafx, fxml

how can i catch the selected value of a fxml combobox and implement it into a javafx class?

i gave the combobox the fx:id "sample" and created a button with onAction="#test" and tried .getValue and .getPromptText.

```
@FXML private ComboBox<String> Sample;

@FXML protected void test( ActionEvent event ) { 
String output = (String) Sample.getValue();
System.out.println(output);

String output = (String) Sample.getPromptText();
System.out.println(output);
}
```

If i try to run it i get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TW_JAVAFX_Undecorator.ButtonController.pruefen(ButtonController.java:60)
    ... 50 more
```

Thanks in advance

Zombie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the code you have in your question should work as long as the case of the combobox identifier in the code matches that of your fxml `fx:id`.

I modified this [JavaFX fxml combo box selection demonstration app](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3062859) to add a button with an onAction method to retrieve a value from the combo box using the comboBox `getValue()` method and it worked fine for me.

Check the case of things, I notice that you say the `fx:id` is `sample`, yet in your code you use `Sample` - and the cases must match otherwise the fxml loader won't inject the node into your controller correctly.

Hard to say if the `NullPointerException` in your code is related to your combo box value retrieval issue as you don't say what the code at `TW_JAVAFX_Undecorator.ButtonController.pruefen(ButtonController.java:60)` is or provide full executable code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
String output = Sample.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This helped me ! I was looking for the right method to get the selected index and item, because getValue is elsewhere and the selected item is here.

Comment: Sample.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()

Answer (score 3):

To get the ComboBox selected value, you can use `Sample.getSelectionModel` method.

**Example:**

```
myComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
    .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                            String oldValue, String newValue) {
            System.out.println("Value is: "+newValue);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an answer for this error (which has just happened to me in same conditions) and found this post.
If you actually declared your ComboBox identifier correctly as jewelsea said (If not anyway I think other error would have appeared).

The fact is everything was well declared (no syntax error or compiling error).
The error is in runtime, the event `@FXML protected void test(ActionEvent event)` is been executing when you fill/add data to your ComboBox.
**But** value property is not changing since no user input has been detected (I'm assuming you're adding data to your ComboBox somewhere else when you initialize the Scene).
So `getValue()` is returning  null.

In this case the line which broken the code is:

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Because output is `null`.

Try to put a breakpoint in the beginning of `test(ActionEvent event)` method.

I expect this help also others.